# Job (step) fails when run as dbo(sa?)

Tags: sql-server, permissions, jobs

I create a job. I add a single step with the following code:

```
insert joblog select getdate(),SUSER_NAME(),current_user    
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ...
```

The job's owner is `sa`. I, as a dev, do not have sa access, but I do have sysadmin.
So I change the job's owner to `sa`.

The job runs fine and the email gets sent. The [joblog] table which I have created to help me understand things shows

```
suser_name=NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT
current_user=dbo
```

Now if I go to the agent's UI, edit the (single) job step, choose page "advanced", and fill the "Run as user" to "dbo", I receive EXECUTE denied on sp_send_dbmail. [joblog] gets one line with

```
susername=sa
current_user=dbo
```

**What is the reason for the error?** `sa` obviously can run the proc. Not only that; `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` also can!

My wild guess is that despite the suser_name inserted in my table, the "run as user" "chooses" dbo as a user in the target db but without any login associated with it, not even `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT`.

Comment: `dbo` isn't a `LOGIN` it's a `USER` and is database scoped. If you aren't running inside `msdb` then you are likely to get that error. A `USER` can only access the database it exists inside.

Comment: @Thom A So is my guess correct? I know dbo is not a login, but I also see `sa` as a result of `suser_name()`

Comment: But you are impersonating the `USER`, not the `LOGIN`. The `LOGIN` returned from `SYSTEM_USER` will be the one linked to the `dbo` user, but that doesn't mean you are impersonating them.

Comment: @Thom A I understand "becoming" dbo in the target db. But I don't understand what happens with the login. Does it get "stripped off"? So the session becomes...login-less? Despite all other jobs using the predefined login? And if this is such, why did suser_name return sa? Shouldn't it return....null? Is there another command, like current_login, which would allow me to understand the flow?

Comment: *"And if this is such, why did suser_name return as? "* As I stated, the `dbo` `USER` is linked to the `sa` login in that database, so `sa` is returned when you ask for that `USER`'s `LOGIN`. That, again, doesn't mean that you are impersonating that `LOGIN`. If `dbo` were linked to a different `LOGIN` then you would get *that* `LOGIN` instead.

Comment: @Thom A after your helpful comments, I found my answer in the `execute as` documentation. If you want to make an answer, please feel free, i'll choose it. Else, I will make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When impersonating a `USER`, in this case `dbo`, then any external database references will fail. A `USER` is a *database* object, and so your impersonation is limited to being scoped within the database. As you are attempting to reference `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` you are, presumably, using 3 part naming as your aren't in `msdb` (which I wouldn't expect you do, as you are `INSERT`ing into a table, and that shouldn't really be done in a system database).

As for why you get `sa`, that's because that's the `LOGIN` that the `dbo` `USER` is linked to. If the `dbo` user was linked to a different `LOGIN` you would get a different `LOGIN`'s name. This does *not*, however, mean that you can impersonate that `LOGIN` by impersonating a `USER`; you strictly cannot do this. As the OP mentions is the comments, this is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The "fix" would be that if you need impersonation, you impersonate a `LOGIN`, not a `USER`, that has access to all the databases you need to access for the specific job.